# Sqoop data to non-default azure storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to import data from SQL database using Sqoop into a different blob storage, other than the default HDInsight cluster blob storage?

Even if I set azure storage access to "Public Blob", I get an error message "Container testcontainer in account nondefaultstorage.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials."

This is the sqoop command I am running:

```
import 
--connect jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServerName;user=sqlLogin;password=sqlPass;database=sqlDbName 
--table tableName 
--target-dir wasb://testcontainer@nondefaultstorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It shall work with linked storage accounts, or public containers.  Public blob won't work because container data is not available.  For more information on the 3 access types, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/#restrict-access-to-containers-and-blobs

Answer (score 0):

Please note that PublicContainer and PublicBlob only grant Read access to all people, you still need Shared Access Signature or Shared Key when writing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the knowledge on sqoop.